# Match exactly one URL segment with regex in Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite these URLs in Wordpress:

```
http://localhost/one/.../
http://localhost/one/...
```

Using the following code:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%my_test%','([^/]*)');

add_rewrite_rule(
    '^one/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?page_id=0&my_test=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

It works, but it also allows URLs like:

```
http://localhost/one/.../...
http://localhost/one/.../.../...
```

How can I rewrite only `/one/.../` and `/one/...` URLs and return 404 for `/one/.../.../` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'^one/([^/]*)/?',` is matching `/one/.../` and `/one/...` and `/one/(nothing)`. Hovewer anything beyond that is ignored because the regex is not terminated. You need to add `$` to the end. And you probably want to replace the `*` with a `+` if you don't want to match `/one/(nothing)` . So, `'^one/([^/]+)/?$',` should work.

[image]